# How to assemble time series data for supervised classification from dictionary output in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, classification, supervised-learning

Could some one please help me out!
I have a dictionary with key and values.Each key is a cluster label, and the values associated with the keys are the data points in that cluster.Each data point is a list with 60 columns(ie, a time series data with length 60).I want to assemble these time series row wise for supervised classification such that the each time series data point has the key(say 0) as its last value in the row as its class.(eg: 0.1,0.3,0.5, 0)where the last value zero is the class value. Here is part of my real data.

```
    {0: array([[ 28.7812,  34.4632,  31.3381, ...,  33.3759,  25.4652,  25.8717],

    [ 24.8923,  25.741 ,  27.5532, ...,  34.2484,  32.1005,  26.691 ],

    [ 31.3987,  30.6316,  26.3983, ...,  33.9002,  29.5446,  29.343 ],
    ..., 
    [ 24.4293,  39.7616,  40.1207, ...,  42.3223,  31.9421,  32.8973],

    [ 32.3175,  39.9719,  40.6855, ...,  28.8281,  41.7112,  35.3453],

    [ 25.7836,  34.1285,  42.6593, ...,  34.4315,  32.155 ,  34.8388]]),

   {1: array([[ 35.7709,  34.396 ,  35.2249, ...,  32.4859,  30.7772,  24.5854],

    [ 24.9706,  33.8315,  46.9423, ...,  24.1889,  11.4137,  13.1961],

    [ 35.5351,  41.7067,  39.1705, ...,  37.7721,  37.2248,  32.9494],
    ..., 
    [ 28.0747,  41.7835,  42.1198, ...,  38.0344,  46.4582,  44.4323],

    [ 33.6696,  38.6754,  39.7419, ...,  34.9395,  36.9095,  39.7494],

    [ 30.5729,  41.0741,  44.9793, ...,  24.353 ,  19.7201,  12.7513]])}
```

In simpler terms, I am only interested in having the values for each row without the brackets and then append it to the row with its key as the last number in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your input format right...

```
input = {0: [['0', '0']], 1: [['0', '0']]}
output = []
for key in input.keys():
    input[key].append(key)
    output.append(input[key])
```

Comment: thanks a lot Thomas. But it throws an error that numpy array has no object attribute append. Also the values in the array are float not string.

Comment: output.append(numpy.append(input[key], key))
You can try the above instead of the 2 lines in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

old_cluster = []

for i in range (0,len(toy_data)):

```
d_cluster =np.append(toy_data[i], int(labels[i]))

f_cluster= d_cluster.tolist()

old_cluster.append(f_cluster)
```

data_cluster=np.asarray(old_cluster)

## Writes Data to a text file without the bracket each point on a line with

## its cluster label as the last point.

with open('mytest.txt','w') as outfile:

```
for item in data_cluster:

    outfile.write("%s\n" % ','.join(map(str,item)))
```